# Logout user script

Tags: script, applescript, apple-remote-desktop

I am trying to create a script in ARD that will let me logout a user.  Now I have a script which does start the logout, but I want it to execute instead of waiting 60 seconds.  The script currently is:

`osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to log out'`

As I said, this works but then I want it to press return on the logout dialog.  The script I tried to make it do that is:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to log out' -e 'keystroke return'
```

which doesn't work.

Is there a way, possibly by telling the system to press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>, to log out without waiting for the timeout to expire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keystroke needs to be within a System Events tell block...

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'log out' -e 'keystroke return' -e end
```

Comment: This worked.  Also, since I am using ARD, it does have a manage menu which has a logout already there.  Can use that also, and skip steps.  Things you learn.

Answer (score 3):

The Apple event is the most robust way to do it (but it can still be blocked by a stuck app).

Entering the special characters is tricky... here's a block you can use in a script or via ARD.

```
osascript -e 'ignoring application responses' -e 'tell application "loginwindow" to «event aevtrlgo»' -e end
```

The « and » characters are typed by option-\ and shift-option-\ respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The `rlgo` (`kAEReallyLogOut`) Apple event logs out without showing a confirmation dialog:

```
tell application "loginwindow" to «event aevtrlgo»
```

`tell application "System Events" to log out` sends `loginwindow` a `logo` (`kAELogOut`) Apple event. The Apple events are listed in `AERegistry.h`.